# Sails.JS how to redirect non-WWW to WWW along with forwarding HTTP to HTTPS

Tags: node.js, redirect, express, https, sails.js

I've tried using this code:

config/http.js

```
  middleware: {

    order: [
       'redirectToWWW',
       'startRequestTimer',
       'cookieParser',
       'session',
       'myRequestLogger',
       'bodyParser',
       'handleBodyParserError',
       'compress',
       'methodOverride',
       'poweredBy',
       '$custom',
       'router',
       'www',
       'favicon',
       '404',
       '500'
    ],

  redirectToWWW: function(req, res, next) {
        var host = req.header("host");
        if (host.match(/^www\..*/i)) {
          next();
        } else {
          res.redirect(301, "https://www." + host);
        }
  }
```

It works fine, but if I got to site/page it redirects me to index of site rather to the https://www version of site/page. Going to site redirects to https://www version of site.

In config/bootstrap.js I forward the port from HTTP to HTTPS (which works as it should), so I'm not sure if this is what's causing the problem

```
if (sails.config.ssl && sails.config.ssl.key && sails.config.ssl.cert) {
        require('express')()
            .get('*', function (req, res) {
                if (sails.config.httpsPort != 443) hostname += ':' + sails.config.httpsPort;
                res.redirect('301', 'https://' + hostname + req.originalUrl)
            }).listen(sails.config.httpPort);
        sails.config.port = sails.config.httpsPort;
    } else {
        sails.config.port = sails.config.httpPort;
    }
```

Comment: I don't have the answer for how to do this in sails, but I'd say this may be something that would be better handled at the load balancer level with apache or nginx.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late reply but it is an issue I recently came across.

Do exactly as you are doing, but you also need to append the request url to the redirect:

```
redirectToWWW: function(req, res, next) {
  var host = req.header("host");
  if (host.match(/^www\..*/i)) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect(301, "https://www." + host + req.url);
  }
}
```

Appending req.url includes the path and also params (e.g. `/foo/bar?id=bla`)

More on the topic can be found in [the sails documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/request-req/req-url).